# grep multiple pattern from single file and store output on separate files for each pattern

Tags: bash, grep

> I have a script to pull metrics of various params from jmx.out file. Is there a way to
>   implement the logic in single command to avoid reading jmx.out file everytime?

```
curl -s "server.hostname.com:12345/jmx"          > jmx.out
cat jmx.out | grep -E "CallQueueLength"          >> call_queue_length.out
cat jmx.out | grep -E "RpcProcessingTimeAvgTime" >> rpc_avg_time.out
cat jmx.out | grep -E "DeleteNumOps"             >> DeleteNumOps.out
cat jmx.out | grep -E "CreateFileOps"            >> CreateFileOps.out
cat jmx.out | grep -E "GetFileInfoNumOps"        >> GetFileInfoNumOps.out
```

Comment: The file names could be changed? Do you have more than 5 params to read?

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
sed -n -e "/CallQueueLength/w call_queue_length.out" -e "/RpcProcessingTimeAvgTime/w rpc_avg_time.out" ...
```

you welcome

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to give a solution with a single command, but following may be helpful :

At first combine all the required pattern assign it to a single variable (it's just for readability) :

```
pattern="RpcProcessingTimeAvgTime|DeleteNumOps|CreateFileOps|GetFileInfoNumOps"
```

Now loop through the grep output and redirect the matched line to a file which name will be the current match omitting other characters :

```
grep -E $pattern jmx.out | while read line 
                            do fileName=`echo $line | grep -oE $pattern | head -1`
                            echo $line >> $fileName
                           done
```

However there is limitation of it. When a line contains multiple matches, it will go to the file named by the pattern which is encountered first. Removing the `head -1` part solves this problem, but the filename won't be appropriate then if a single line contains same pattern multiple times.